# Comparing strings in python 2.7

Tags: string, python-2.7

This is my code:

```
for films in filmlist:
    with codecs.open('peliculas.txt', encoding='utf8', mode='r') as lfile:
        filmsDone = lfile.read()
        filmsDoneList = filmsDone.split(',')

    if films not in filmsDoneList:
        with codecs.open('peliculas.txt', encoding='utf8', mode='a+') as lfile:
            lfile.write(films.strip() + ',')
```

It will never recognize the last item of the list.
I have printed filmsDoneList and the last item in PyCharm looks like this: `u'X Men.Primera Generacion'`. I have printed films and they looks like this: `X Men.Primera Generacion'`

So I have no idea where is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should also explain what those txt files contain and what is your goal.

Comment: Well, Its a file that contains all parsed titles from my Db. if I add a new title I want Python to compare the file txt in order to check if exists or not. then do

Comment: Instead of separating your titles with a comma, I suggest you to organize your titles differently in your .txt file: 1 title per line. This will make things a lot easier since you can do the following steps. 1) open the file using `fopen()`; 2) use `readlines()` to create a python list in which 1 element is 1 title, so you don't need the `split()` command; 3) iterate over such list with a for loop in order to check if a given title exists or not.

Comment: Tks vm. Really helped this answer. I am now working on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rafa, for you to better understand what I meant in the comments, I had to write an entire answer in order for me to attach codes and screenshots.
Let's say the `peliculas.txt` file has the following format:
[image]

You can import such file in python according the following 3 commands:

```
fileIN=open('peliculas.txt','r')
filmsDoneList=fileIN.readlines()
fileIN.close()
```

So you basically open the file, import each line thanks to `readlines()` and then close the file because its contents are available in `filmsDoneList`. The latter has the following contents (in PyCharm):

[image]

Obviously this list is quite long and does not fit in my screen, but you get the point.
You can now get rid of that annoying newline tag `'\r\n'` by means of the following loop:

```
for id in range(len(filmsDoneList)):
    filmsDoneList[id]=filmsDoneList[id].strip()
```

and now `filmsDoneList` has the form:
[image]
much better now, innit?

Now, let's say you want to add the following films:

```
newFilms=['The Exorcist','Back to the Future','Aliens','Back to the Future']
```

To make your code more robust, I have added Back to the Future twice. Basically you can get rid of duplicates in `newFilms` by means of the `set()` function. This will convert `newFilms` in a `set` with duplicates removed, but we will convert it back to a list thanks to this command:

```
newFilms=list(set(newFilms))
```

and now `newFilms` has the form:

[image]

Now that everything has been sorted, it's time to check if items in `newFilms` already are in `filmsDoneList` which, recall, is the contents of `peliculas.txt`.

Reopen `peliculas.txt` as follows:

```
fileOUT=open('peliculas.txt','a')
```

the `'a'` tag means "append", so basically everything you write will be added to the file without removing anything from it.
And the main loop goes:

```
for film in newFilms:
    if film in filmsDoneList:
        pass
    else:
        fileOUT.write(film+'\n')
```

the `pass` means "do nothing". The `write` commands also appends the newline tag to the movie title: this will keep the previous format of 1 title per line. At the end of this loop you might as well close `fileOUT`.
The resulting `peliculas.txt` is
[image]

and, as you can see, Back to the Future was in `newFilms` but wasn't appended to the end of this file because already was in it. As instead, The Exorcist and Aliens have been appended to this file, at the bottom.

If your file has titles separated by commas, this approach is still valid. However you must add

```
filmsDoneList=filmsDoneList[0].split(',')
```

after the first for loop. Also in the `write` function (in the last for loop) you might want to replace the newline value with a comma.

This approach is cleaner, I reckon will also fix the problem you've been having and avoids continuous open/close files in a loop. Hope this helps!